# How to remove Fade Animation in CATransition

Tags: ios, swift, animation, catransition

I've tried to remove Fade animation between two views by changing background color of views to clearcolor **and** remove FadeIn/Out by using

```
 self.navigationController!.view.layer.removeAnimationForKey("FadeIn")
 self.navigationController!.view.layer.removeAnimationForKey("FadeOut")
```

**and** follow according to answer below,

[Anyway to remove fade when using CATransition between 2 views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027235/anyway-to-remove-fade-when-using-catransition-between-2-views)

still get fade animation. Following is my code.

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 1
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight      
self.navigationController!.view.layer.removeAnimationForKey("FadeIn")                 
self.navigationController!.view.layer.removeAnimationForKey("FadeOut")
self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution?